Android Webview not getting actual url which shows on address bar like chrome | Android Studio Java
package com.example.flipkartwebview;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.EditText;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView webView;
    private EditText editText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                String url = request.getUrl().toString();
                Log.d("WebView", "shouldOverrideUrlLoading: " + url);
                editText.setText(url);
                return false; // Allow WebView to load the URL
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, android.graphics.Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                Log.d("WebView", "onPageStarted: " + url);
                editText.setText(url);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                Log.d("WebView", "onPageFinished: " + url);
                editText.setText(url);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onLoadResource(view, url);
                Log.d("WebView", "onLoadResource: " + url);
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
                Log.e("WebView", "onReceivedError: " + failingUrl + " - " + description);
            }
        });

        webView.loadUrl("https://www.flipkart.com");
    }
}

I'm trying to make a simple webbrowser first as example I'm opening webpage https://flipkart.com/
then when I'm doing some work like any product click or any other work webview not getting the specific url which I can show on addressbar.
as time of when I'm interacting with product or try to login everything working as expected just not getting actual url like chrome show on address bar or any other browser shows on addressbar.
How to fix this issue??
Output I've got like these below which is not actual url except first one
2024-05-31 20:50:13.498 17893-17893 WebView                 com.example.flipkartwebview          D  onPageStarted: https://www.flipkart.com/

2024-05-31 20:50:13.602 17893-17893 WebView                 com.example.flipkartwebview          D  onLoadResource: https://static-assets-web.flixcart.com/batman-returns/batman-returns/p/images/fkheaderlogo_exploreplus_mobile-39120d.svg

2024-05-31 20:50:13.602 17893-17893 WebView                 com.example.flipkartwebview          D  onLoadResource: https://static-assets-web.flixcart.com/batman-returns/batman-returns/p/images/profile-52e0dc.svg

2024-05-31 20:50:13.604 17893-17893 WebView                 com.example.flipkartwebview          D  onLoadResource: https://static-assets-web.flixcart.com/batman-returns/batman-returns/p/images/fkplus-4ff29a.svg

2024-05-31 20:50:13.604 17893-17893 WebView                 com.example.flipkartwebview          D  onLoadResource: https://static-assets-web.flixcart.com/batman-returns/batman-returns/p/images/orders-bfe8c4.svg


2024-05-31 20:50:13.607 17893-17893 WebView                 com.example.flipkartwebview          D  onLoadResource: https://static-assets-web.flixcart.com/batman-returns/batman-returns/p/images/rewards-fbd212.svg

2024-05-31 20:50:13.607 17893-17893 WebView                 com.example.flipkartwebview          D  onLoadResource: https://static-assets-web.flixcart.com/batman-returns/batman-returns/p/images/giftCard-bd87e1.svg


You are logging information to Logcat, which should include the URL. What are you getting?

resources and some internal api not a valid actual url (like address bar of chrome)

You might consider editing your question and showing the actual Logcat output.

other basic app available on play store those also getting why not in my case

@CommonsWare edited please check
only first is onPageStarted
rest all onLoadResource

I suggested that you add Logcat output. For example, your source code contains Log.d("WebView", "onPageStarted: " + url);. We need to see the Logcat output, including both the labels like onPageStarted:  and the URLs that follow those labels. The simplest thing would be to copy and paste the Logcat output into your question. The onPageStarted and onPageFinished lines should represent Web pages, and you should get the URLs of those pages in the Logcat output.

Great! Next, click a link in the WebView. You should get a fresh set of Logcat output, showing the new page being loaded. In particular, look at the onPageStarted and onPageFinished lines.

@CommonsWare no logcat for onPageStarted and onPageFinished
